# How can I remove file name from path? (Makefile)

Tags: makefile

I want to convert "**./folder/file.o**" to "**./folder**".

How can I do this in make?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to use ($dir ./folder/file).
[File-Name-Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)